# making a CheckBox in a grid accepting 0 as false

Tags: gridview, checkbox, devexpress

Is it possible to make a check box column accept 0 and 1 to determine whether it should be checked or not? I am getting the dataSource for the gridView from a database and one of the columns there are using a 0 or 1 as true and false. I need this 0 and 1 to represent checked or not checked in the gridView. I know I can make a loop to go through every single record in the dataTable and change the value to checked or not checked but there are literally thousands of entries, so doing this way could be slow, especially on the machines that are going to use it. Is it possible to force the gridView checkbox column in this way?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**From:** [customize RepositoryItemCheckEdit display](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q481844)

I think the best way to achieve this goal is to change the column type to `Int32` (for example) and map `0, 1, 2` values to the `false, true, indeterminate` states via the
[RepositoryItemCheckEdit.ValueUnchecked](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsRepositoryRepositoryItemCheckEdit_ValueUncheckedtopic),
RepositoryItemCheckEdit.ValueChecked,
RepositoryItemCheckEdit.ValueGrayed properties.

Please make sure that your database field (which is bound to this column) is a string type field and contains "0","1" and "2" values.
If it's an integer field, please modify your code as follows :

```
 repchk.ValueChecked = CType(2, Integer)
 repchk.ValueUnchecked = CType(0, Integer)
 repchk.ValueGrayed = CType(1, Integer)
```

Please try this solution and inform us about your results.

**References**:
[How to use RepositoryItemCheckEdit in XtraGrid Column for a dataTable column containing only "True"/"False" values.](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q433632)
[xtragrid - Checkbox column](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q320725)
[Set checkbox cheched in RepositoryItemCheckEdit](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q322551)
[RepositoryItemCheckEdit](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q244627)

Comment: This worked 100% and its nice and simple to understand too, thanks

Comment: @Niranjan Kala +1 excellent! I've absolutely forgotten about this simple feature)))

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Unbound Columns](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument1477) to accomplish this task in general situation(convert the column of one type into column of another type):

```
using DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base;
//...
gridControl1.DataSource = new List<DataObj> { 
    new DataObj{ ID=0, intFlag=0 },
    new DataObj{ ID=1, intFlag=1 },
    new DataObj{ ID=2, intFlag=0 }
};
gridView1.PopulateColumns();
gridView1.Columns["intFlag"].Visible = false;
gridView1.Columns.Add(new DevExpress.XtraGrid.Columns.GridColumn()
{
    FieldName = "boolFlag",
    Caption = "Flag",
    UnboundType = DevExpress.Data.UnboundColumnType.Boolean,
    Visible = true
});
gridView1.CustomUnboundColumnData += gridView1_CustomUnboundColumnData;
//...
void gridView1_CustomUnboundColumnData(object sender, CustomColumnDataEventArgs e) {
    if(e.Column.FieldName == "boolFlag") {
        if(e.IsGetData)
            e.Value = (int)gridView1.GetRowCellValue(e.ListSourceRowIndex, "intFlag") == 1;
        if(e.IsSetData)
            gridView1.SetRowCellValue(e.ListSourceRowIndex, "intFlag", (bool)e.Value ? 1 : 0);
    }
}
```